# Graded watching for Spanish

Tags: resource-request, spanish, listening

I'm wondering if there are any resources for "graded watching" in Spanish. I've made a similar post for Korean, my other target language.

This is a resource that I saw someone mention somewhere online which lists shows and movies for advanced Chinese learners: http://www.jiong3.com/gradedwatching/.

If you know of any similar resources for Spanish, I would love to hear about them, regardless of what language proficiency they're targeted towards! I'm only upper beginner right now but anything would be helpful! If the resources you know of "grade" shows/movies but in a very different way to the above site, that would be just as useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of one resource that has something similar to graded watching: [Dreaming Spanish on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/c/DreamingSpanish)

According to the channel description,

> Dreaming Spanish is the biggest resource of Spanish Comprehensible Input.

The videos are “graded” into 4 playlists:

Superbeginner, Beginner, Intermediate, Advanced

Answer (score 1):

"Extra en español" is a series in spanish for beginners/learners of the language . They speak clearly and slowly and use comprehensible input.
The series has a similar format to the TV show "Friends". It's on YouTube.
You can decide to turn on or off the subs (CC) - depends on which channel you decide to watch the show from. Some channels have it hard subbed.

BTW the series exists in 3 other languages : English, French and German.
Also there's a youtube channel similar to Dreaming Spanish as mentioned above. It's called "Spanish After Hours".